# Why is the output of this code 3 for the below test case?

Tags: java, sorting, priority-queue

My coding question has to do with counting the minimum number of rooms given scheduling times

Given an array of meeting time intervals consisting of start and end times [[s1,e1],[s2,e2],...] (si < ei), find the minimum number of conference rooms required.
Example
Example1
Input: intervals = [(0,30),(5,10),(15,20)]
Output: 2
Explanation:
We need two meeting rooms
room1: (0,30)
room2: (5,10),(15,20)
Example2
Input: intervals = [(2,7)]
Output: 1
Explanation: 
Only need one meeting room

This is the test case I am trying so solve: [(65,424),(351,507),(314,807),(387,722),(19,797),(259,722),(165,221)]

The output is supposed to be 6, but my code is returning 3 and I am not sure why.

When I ran this test case, [(65,424),(351,507),(314,807),(387,722),(19,797),(259,722)], my solution prints 6, however, as soon as I add (165,221), the solution prints 3.

``
The code is below:

```
/**
 *Definition of Interval:
 * public classs Interval {
 *     int start, end;
 *     Interval(int start, int end) {
 *         this.start = start;
 *         this.end = end;
 *     }
 * }
 */

public class Solution {
    /**
     * @param intervals: an array of meeting time intervals
     * @return: the minimum number of conference rooms required
     */

public int minMeetingRooms(List<Interval> intervals) {
        // Write your code here
        if(intervals.size() == 0 || intervals == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        Interval[] interArr = new Interval[intervals.size()];
        interArr = intervals.toArray(interArr);
        Arrays.sort(interArr, (a,b) -> a.start - b.start);
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
        pq.add(interArr[0].end);
        for(int i = 1; i < interArr.length; i++) {
            Interval curr = interArr[i];
            if (curr.start < pq.peek()) {
                pq.add(interArr[i].end);
            }
        }
        return pq.size();
    }
}

``
```

Comment: Could you please explain the logic to determine how many rooms are needed?

Comment: Yes, so if meetings do not overlap (start time > end time),  then only one room is needed between both meetings, however if there is overlap, at least 2  rooms are needed.

Comment: adding `(165, 221)` the smallest end is `221` (head of queue) - there are (kind of) 2 other elements which start before `221` and so will be added, including `(165,221)` // without that interval, all intervals are added since `start` is always less than first `end`

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use this as an interview question.

Simply put, your output is incorrect *because* your algorithm is incorrect. You've basically written a test case that *demonstrates* your algorithm is incorrect.

Hint, you don't need a priority queue. The problem is simpler than you think.

Comment: That makes sense. I don't understand why the algorithm is incorrect though.

Comment: we just need to time the overlap time period and maximum overlaped is the no of room require. so do you ask for  space complexity also or just need the anser in O(1)?, fyi got this question in interview today so was asked to do in o(1) space complexity